# Am I allowed to ask for translation references and/or suggestions in MSE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, languages

Well, there's not much more to say than what the title already suggests. I'd like to know if there are some common translations (i.e. some widely used and accepted translations) from English to Italian of some technical words from sheaf theory. Can I make such a request in MSE?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/368006/79365) got +6, so it looks like the answer is yes. There's even a tag `mathematical-french`. Although I guess it's not necessary to create `mathematical-x` for every language; the tag `terminology` should suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There have been not dissimilar questions asked in the past, and even a [translation-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-request) tag created.  As long as you have specific terms you wish translated into Italian, I cannot see there being a problem with such a question.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!